# Looking for arguments: who decides about network connection technology: customer or supplier

Tags: networking, client-relations

I work for a supplier of software solutions, and when we want to deliver our solutions to the network of a customer, we are forced to use a myriad of tools: VPN connection over GlobalProtect, VPN connection over PulseSecure or another FortiClient, ...

**Edit:** it's the idea that we deliver support to our customers, while not needing to go onsite to our customers. In order to do this, we need to connect to our customers' network, for which different technologies and tools are currently used.

As a supplier, we would like, either to bundle all those different tools, either to enforce one single way of working, using one single tool.

Obviously, customers have the tendency to keep using that one tool they are used to, and they are not willing to change.

There can be different approaches to this situation:

- "Supplier: deal with it!"
- "Customer: this and that are arguments for which we would like to adopt this one tool."

Can anybody provide me with arguments in favour/disfavour for the supplier and for the customer for this situation? (I can imagine many software firms needing to deal with this)

Thanks in advance

Oh, I'm a regular user of StackOverflow, but this question is not fit for that site. Neither  is this question fit for the "NetworkEngineering" discussion forum. If you find this question not fit for this forum either, please indicate a more suitable one.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "deliver our solutions to the network of a customer" and in what way you need to use that myriad of tools that is inconvenient to you?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: I've edited my question, adding some background information.

Comment: It’s probably more of a business question. Using the tools you prefer has a lower cost for your company and using the tools the customer prefers has a higher cost for your company. The solution is simple: charge more when the customer demands you use the tools they prefer.

Comment: "Customer is always right", largely because if you disagree with them enough they stop being your customer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a not-so-good fit for a number of sites, but I don't know a really good one.

In general the deployment process should be subject to contractual agreements between customer and supplier, and it should be negotiated early if at least one side isn't really flexible. Since customer networks are often managed by the customer or another organization working for the customer, don't expect too much flexibility there. Every deviation from established procedures in networking can introduce security risks, and these weigh a lot more than inconveniences to the supplier/contractor for a limited time.

So as a supplier/contractor, make sure you're flexible regarding the tools to be used (apart from the development tools that you use internally, these are normally not the customer's business) but speak the language of the relevant people at the customer's organization as you will need to communicate clearly with them. Being knowledgeable in their area and respecting their expertise goes a long way towards getting good results.

*Edit after your question's edit:* When providing long-term support (as opposed to just one-time installation) your preferences as a supplier may weigh a bit more, but it's still "their network, their rules". You may be able to put a price tag on customer requirements that make your work more tedious, and use that as a base for negotiating which way your services are most cost-effective for the customer. They may still decide to pay a little more in exchange for keeping their way of working.